# for-loop problems changing property of all objects in array

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, uilabel

My first time and I hope this is/was not only a problem for me.

Upfront, I create and do all stuff without .nib, .xib or storyboard and am quite new to Xcode.

Problem description:

I create a series of labels, that go into an array all programmatically.

int i is below or equal 4 else it does not fire anyway.

```
int i = (int)[players count];

if (i<=4) {

    nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width-(self.view.bounds.size.width/3)-20*widthmultiplayer, self.view.bounds.size.height-((50*heightmultibplyer)*i)-50*heightmultibplyer, (self.view.bounds.size.width/3), 50*heightmultibplyer)];
    nameLabel.text = enterName.text;

    [nameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:fontSize]];
    [nameLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
    [self.view addSubview:nameLabel];
    players[i] = nameLabel;
    NSLog(@"index: %i , name:%@", i, nameLabel.text);

    enterName.text = @"";
}
```

then I hide all labels programmatically with following code

```
for (UILabel *label in players) {
    label.hidden = YES;
}
```

Now the funny part - when I want to show them again using

```
for (UILabel *label in players) {
    label.hidden = NO;
}
```

it does not show the last entry.

Meaning:

- if I have only 1 entry it shows nothing
- if I have 3 entries it only shows 2
- and so on and so on...

Funny thing is my Log of the array shows all objects, shows the correct index of each object and the hidden status as false (-so what it should be).

Tried to bring the views to front by

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:label]
```

but that wouldn't work as well.

I can't figure out why.  Answers and tips on what I do wrong would be highly appreciated.

---- EDIT ----
I found a workaround to my problem, maybe this helps someone:
i changed the change of the hidden value a little by doing this:

```
        for (UILabel *label in players) {
        [label removeFromSuperview];
        label.hidden = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:label];
    }
```

looks cheesy, is cheesy, but works.
Still if someone can help me find a solution or the major bug, i would really love it.

Comment: Why are you casting return values to ints? This might cause problems when building for 32 vs 64 bit.

Comment: Did you log `int i = (int)[players count]`?

Comment: @Joride: the int i I just use to figure out the needed index for the next

Comment: @Himanshu Joshi: also logged this one, but also when I Log the array players i have correct entries - first one has 0 - sure because the players count is 0 when it is empty and so next count 1 so next index 1.

Comment: The -count method of NSArray returns an NSInteger; why cast it to an int? Someday you will get into trouble with this practice..

Comment: True, should change the int to nsinteger right from the beginning, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I worked the whole theory part in this question and the result i got is that it worked properly without any issues

Here is the code i used for testing

```
players=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:3];


for (int k=0; k<10; k++) {
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width-(self.view.bounds.size.width/3)-20*widthmultiplayer, self.view.bounds.size.height-((50*heightmultibplyer)*k)-50*heightmultibplyer, (self.view.bounds.size.width/3), 50*heightmultibplyer)));

}
int i=0;
CGRect rect=CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width-(self.view.bounds.size.width/3)-20*widthmultiplayer, self.view.bounds.size.height-((50*heightmultibplyer)*i)-50*heightmultibplyer, (self.view.bounds.size.width/3), 50*heightmultibplyer);
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(rect));
nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:rect];
[nameLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[nameLabel.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
[self.view addSubview:nameLabel];
players[0] = nameLabel;


i=1;
nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width-(self.view.bounds.size.width/3)-20*widthmultiplayer, self.view.bounds.size.height-((50*heightmultibplyer)*i)-50*heightmultibplyer, (self.view.bounds.size.width/3), 50*heightmultibplyer)];
[nameLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[nameLabel.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];

[self.view addSubview:nameLabel];

players[1] = nameLabel;
NSLog(@"%@",players);
i = (int)[players count];
if (i<=4) {
    NSLog(@"%@",players);
    nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width-(self.view.bounds.size.width/3)-20*widthmultiplayer, self.view.bounds.size.height-((50*heightmultibplyer)*i)-50*heightmultibplyer, (self.view.bounds.size.width/3), 50*heightmultibplyer)];
    [nameLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [nameLabel.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
    [self.view addSubview:nameLabel];
    players[i] = nameLabel;
    NSLog(@"index: %i , name:%@", i, nameLabel.text);

    NSLog(@"%@",players);
}    
for (UILabel *label in players) {
    label.hidden = YES;
}
NSLog(@"%@",players);
for (UILabel *label in players) {
    label.hidden = NO;
}

NSLog(@"%@",players);
```

Now the Explanation of what may have went wrong.This case can occour due to the reason that  **one of the label added into the array is not added into the view**.That is the reason when you re-add it turns to be working

Comment: true, but my main problem is ... longer explanation: I create the labels in, let's say viewNr1., and they all show up. When I switch to viewNr2. and hide them, switch back to viewNr1. and unhide them, one is missing. as i just hide the 'views' so its actually a list of views that lie above each other, and are hidden, unhidden as needed.

Comment: although my problem only works in the workaround, the explanation is the best for someone having similar issues, always check that you add your subviews correctly! Thanks, if i come up with a more detailed description or the pit-trap i fell into, i will update this.

Answer (score 0):

The `NSArray` indexes start at 0. You have to go from 0 to `[players count] - 1`.

Comment: array players has correct entries - first one has 0 - sure because the players count is 0 when it is empty, than i add one entry, so the count is 1 and the next needed index is also 1 if i would set the index to [players count]-1 than i would always overwrite the previous entry and never exceed a count of 1.

Comment: Are using an NSArray(Not an NSMutableArray). And if you are, have you added a nil object at the end?

Comment: I misinterpreted your code, then. I will delete my answer when the relevant comments are not important anymore. I would be good if you showed the declaration of `players`.

Comment: Did you log the `for`enumerations?

Comment: am using an NSMutableArray actually, i allocate it and fill it up on the run. Also logged the for enumerations, everything is perfect in the log, the thing just wont show

Comment: @user3071962 if possible and allowed please leave your answer, if i could upvote it i would (lacking reputation) but this a thing a lot of newcomers (as i am one) forget quite frequently